# Roslyn SyntaxTree Diff

Tags: syntax, diff, abstract-syntax-tree, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Let's say I have two `SyntaxTree`s **A** and **B**,
where **B** has been produced by applying changes to **A**.

I would like to get the following information:

- SyntaxNodes & Tokens that have been removed from **A** to produce **B**
- SyntaxNodes & Tokens that have been added to **A** to produce **B**

Is there an API for this?
If not, how can this be efficiently computed?

This information must be available to Roslyn,
since unchanged `GreenNode`s are shared between the trees.

One solution I can think of is to use `SyntaxTree.GetChangedSpans()`
and then lookup the intersecting tokens.
However that feels like a hack and I'm not sure if it is always accurate.
A small text change might have a large impact on a `SyntaxTree`:
(e.g. replacing `*` with `+` in an expression might change its order/precedence)

Comment: If you really have two ASTs and access to them, this seem straightforward.  Make a list of the nodes of A, and the nodes of B.   nodes(A)-Green are those that have been deleted.  nodes(B)-Green are those that have been added.  All you need to do is do a tree walk, build some sets and do  set subtracts.   I'm not a Rosyln user, but is this hard?

Comment: I think it is not possible to do this efficiently for technical reasons. (cannot use `HashSets` because of the "unstable" `GetHashCode()` implementation of the Nodes). Equality works: `SyntaxNode.IsEquivalentTo()`. However I would like to avoid to compare every node in **A** to every node in **B** bcs O(n^2).

Comment: So Roslyn disappoints.  (I build a system that does something like Rosyln does, and my suggested method would work just fine; in fact we have a "smart differencer" that works by a much more spectactular comparison of the trees, in a much smarter way.  See my bio).

Comment: Do your syntax trees have a shared history? Or are you re-parsing them from scratch between changes?

Comment: The Smart Differencer parses two separate files, and then constructs a plausible set of editing actions to produce one from the other, using the isomorphic-under-renaming subtrees that happen to match. See http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/SmartDifferencer/CSharpSmartDifferencerExample.html If you want to know, given one AST, how you got another, with our more general transformation tools, you'd simply record the set of node changes you made; we don't keep an immutable original around.

Comment: @JoshVarty: Yes, they have a shared history. I can see that they share internal `GreenNode`s as described in [Eric Lippert's blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2012/06/08/persistence-facades-and-roslyns-red-green-trees/). However there is no public API for to access the `GreenNode`s.

Comment: @IraBaxter: thanks for your suggestions, but I'll have to stick to Roslyn right now for various reasons. I have checked your profile and website before. You're hard to avoid when browsing AST related stuff on SO ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We [internally have a differ](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Compilers/Core/Portable/Syntax/SyntaxDiffer.cs) that lives in the compiler layer and thus uses green nodes, we just haven't exposed it as an API. This is what we use to drive GetChangedSpans, actually. We *intentionally* didn't expose green nodes directly because that's an implementation detail.

There's no specific reason that API couldn't be public. I think when this one came around we were worried about how one actually specs what the behavior is, or what's a minimal "goodness" you can expect from the diff. That, and we didn't have a motivating scenario to actually make sure our work was useful.

Comment: This answers the first question: there is no public API. Any chance that the `SyntaxDiffer` can become public? (pull request?). Or can we work around it using `SyntaxTree.GetChangedSpans` or `SyntaxTree.GetChanges`?

Comment: Aside: Where should I ask questions about the Roslyn API? SO, GitHub, MSDN? (e.g. "what is the difference between `SyntaxTree.GetChangedSpans` and `SyntaxTree.GetChanges`")

Comment: You could totally submit a pull request. I'd first suggest you open a bug on GitHub just so people know there's a problem and there's some representation that you're actually doing the work. That will also let people chime in with any issues they know about that you'll want to fix before making it public. Maybe this code is actually buggy as everything and that's why we didn't make it public. A "drive by" pull request just changing the access modifiers to public would be rejected just because we have to maintain a supported, thought-out, well-formed API. :-)

Comment: As far as questions go, StackOverflow or GitHub are both great forums. We have a Gitter channel too.